# Floatable element into td element

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-table

I cannot get this style to work.  Take a look at my drawing:

[image]

Markup:

```
<h1Title</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <dfn>help</dfn>
            <a href="link0.php">
            <span>text</span></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="link1.html">
            <span>text</span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to make the `<td>` element clickable by using the `<a>` element as a block. But, I need to put a small "header" with `<dfn>` element inside the `<td>` too. I can make the `<dfn>` align to top-right and *preserve* the `<a>` vertical text align relative to its container without conflicting with `<dfn>` when it exists.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you need the `dfn` to be un-clickable?

Comment: yes, and also be posicioned at top-right. Post updated!

Comment: let me know if more details are required

Comment: Please post a picture and not a link to whatever that ridiculous flockdraw thing is. Use a service like imgur.com if you don't have the rep to upload.

Comment: @j08691 relax! there is no reason be angry :)

Comment: Does this need to be in a table?

Comment: yes, it is a table with 7 columns, and 23 rows simulating a weekly calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your markup bit and added some positioning and padding to get something close to the image you posted:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="cellContainer">
                <dfn>help</dfn>
                <a href="link0.php">text</a>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="link1.html">text</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.cellContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px 0;
}
a {
    background: grey;
    padding: 12px 24px;
}
dfn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LuwtM/3/)**

The borders in the demo represent the cell borders. The grey background is the link area.

Comment: The problem here is that `<dfn>help</dfn>` is clickable, where it should not.

Comment: @manix I've updated my answer so that the `dfn` is no longer clickable (but the rest of the cell is). Is this closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: I like your `<span class="cellContainer">` as `relative` to make use of `absolute` in `dfn` :D Thank you so much!